# C# simple stopwatch - Total beginner

Tags: c#, system.timers.timer

I come from embedded C programming and I don't absolutely know anything about oop, task, threads, ecc..
I'm figuring out the basics concepts of C# and oop and wanted to try coding a simple stopwatch.

Goal: Toggle the stopwatch state with a button and show the value inside the button itself.

So far I've come to this:

```cs
namespace Cronometro
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }

    public class MyTimerClass
    {
        private DateTime TimeValue;
        private System.Timers.Timer TimerObj;
        private const int TimeInterval = 1;

        public MyTimerClass()
        {
            TimeValue new DateTime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
            TimerObj = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeInterval);
            TimerObj.AutoReset = true;

            TimerObj.Elapsed += TimerObj_Elapsed;
        }

        private void TimerObj_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            TimeValue = TimeValue.AddMilliseconds((double)TimeInterval);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            TimerObj.Start();
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            TimerObj.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Come to this point, I just wanted to print the value with Button.Content but seems like I cannot use it outside of the `MainWindow` class.

What should I do? I started thinking about creating a task inside the main class and wait for the timer event to print the value but I know nothing about threads and tasks.

Comment: First, add a button onto the form. Without a button, you won't be able to press it.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the `Timer` class? You don't seem to be adding any value there, so just use it in your main class without the wrapper and handle the elapsed event.

Comment: I can see your point @RonBeyer, but it was just to practice classes.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you mean, as at the moment you can't use it in the `MainWindow` class at all. Just expose the value via a public function, and you can fetch the instance's value anywhere you want.

```
namespace Cronometro
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var x = new MyTimerClass();       // <<<
            x.Start();                        // <<<
            var timeValue = x.GetTimeValue(); // <<<
        }
    }

public class MyTimerClass
{
    private DateTime TimeValue;
    private System.Timers.Timer TimerObj;
    private const int TimeInterval = 1;

    public MyTimerClass()
    {
        TimeValue new DateTime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
        TimerObj = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeInterval);
        TimerObj.AutoReset = true;

        TimerObj.Elapsed += TimerObj_Elapsed;
    }

    private void TimerObj_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeValue = TimeValue.AddMilliseconds((double)TimeInterval);
    }

    public DateTime GetTimeValue() // <<<
    {                              // <<<
        return TimeValue;          // <<<
    }                              // <<<

    public void Start()
    {
        TimerObj.Start();
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        TimerObj.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: I found out the dispatcher thing, seems like it's the solution to the problem? Timer and UI run in different threads, so it's not just a matter of object scope.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have to write your own Stopwatch class. DotNet has its own:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8

Second, try to understand async/await pattern:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

So, you can do something like this:
https://wouterdekort.com/2013/10/01/async-and-await-and-the-ui-thread/

Comment: async/await for a stopwatch? to do what? there is no async operation in here

Answer (score 0):

One way you could populate the button text is you create an event in the `MyTimerClass` class, and attach a listener delegate to it from inside the `MainWindow` class.

Then, fire the event in `TimerObj_Elapsed` in `MyTimerClass`, so that the event handler in `MainWindow` will be called, and you will have a chance to populate the button.

However, there is something other than "practicing class" you have to deal with. Because you are using a thread pool timer, so the `Elapsed` event handler of the timer is invoked from a worker thread. In a GUI app, only the main / UI thread can interactive with controls. So chances are, you will get an exception when trying to set `Button.Text`. You will need to marshal the set action to the UI thread.

Frankly, if you are practicing writing classes in C#, I'd recommend you using a Console App to start with rather than a GUI app. It is probably not a good idea if people throwing out too many concepts on the table that you don't know at the same time.

Comment: You're right this is getting too complicated for my current knowledge. I tought this was going to be simple as a first project but at this point it's clear it wasn't

Comment: You’re practicing communication between window class and a background timer which is not a beginning topic. If you want to use a timer, start with one window class and use winform timer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Or DispatcherTimer if project is WPF